# Does Lynx have a view similar to Browser "Reader view"

Tags: lynx

Is there a Reader view for [Lynx](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/%5D)?

to explain trying to find answers to the following questions:

- is there a Reader view (similar to [Firefox: Reader View](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-reader-view-clutter-free-web-pages))?
- is it possible to create add-in or extension?
- is it possible to modify the default view?
- is there a 'issue list' where i could request such a feature? (I am aware of mailing group [Lynx-dev](https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lynx-dev))

The default [Lynx](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/%5D) layout includes everything on the web page, This can be frustrating as there are often large menus and other content not related to the main body content.

I absolutely love [Lynx](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/%5D), its simplicity and speed make browsing for most sites preferable. I still use Firefox with [JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) sites.

My experienced is mostly with Java and scripting languages and haven't coded using [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) flavors, hence doing it myself isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Lynx, to my knowledge, does not support anything like add-ins or extensions. Lynx is a bit more monolithic than other software you'd encounter these days.

So, you'd really add that feature by adding it to the Lynx code base itself, and making it available, e.g. through key bindings.

How that could work is, in all honesty, a topic that you should rather discuss on the [lynx-dev mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lynx-dev/) with the actual developers.

Now, do **I** assess that to be a feasible feature for Lynx? Maybe.

Your firefox [guesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661650/how-does-firefox-reader-view-operate) which document elements are the main text based on heuristics that involve things like tag name, textual content statistics, and CSS classes. When you look at the source code of that `Readability` repo, you see that it extensively uses DOM properties for that. Quick glance at the Lynx approach to handling HTML documents tells me that will be a bit harder within the Lynx source code, and you'll possibly start doing interesting things *while* parsing the document.

> My experienced is mostly with Java and scripting languages and haven't coded using C flavors, hence doing it myself isn't an option.

Well, hm, then Lynx probably simply can't do what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I like the simplicity of Lynx, are you familiar with similar packages that aren't as monolithic, like: w3m; Lynx; Links2; brow.sh; netrik; emacs w3; retawq. (I tried Elinks it didnt suit my needs)